# Java Swing GUI user interactions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm currently working on a pizza ordering program on eclipse using java.

I seem to be stuck right now; I'm not sure how to expose more user interactions after the user has already performed one.

I want to add another one so that when a topping is picked, it will go on to another set of buttons.

I'm not too familiar with Swing GUIs so I'm a bit confused on what I should try and do in order to have more buttons added to my program.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.swing.*;
//Import used to add interfaces in order to use more commands and to be able to use GUI.

public class PizzaMain implements ActionListener{
    final static String LABEL_TEXT = "Please choose the size of your pizza:";
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane;
    JLabel label;
    JButton button, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6;
//Button 4,5,6 will be used for more toppings.
//JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, & JButton is used for adding the variables of all the buttons, panels, labels, and frame so they're able to be added into the JPanel in GUI.  

    public PizzaMain() {
        frame = new JFrame("EAST SIDE PIZZA");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));

        label = new JLabel (LABEL_TEXT);
        label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        contentPane.add(label);
        label.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.ITALIC, 15));

        button = new JButton("Small");
        button.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        button.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button.setActionCommand("Small");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(button);
        button.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                button.setVisible(true);
                button.setText("Pepperoni");
                button2.setText("Cheese");
                button3.setVisible(true);
                button3.setText("Pineapple");
                button4 = new JButton("Mushrooms");
                button4.setActionCommand("Mushrooms");
                button4.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button4);
                button5 = new JButton("Peppers");
                button5.setActionCommand("Peppers");
                button5.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button5);
                button6 = new JButton("Bacon");
                button6.setActionCommand("Bacon");
                button6.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button6);
                label.setVisible(true);
                label.setText("Please choose what topping you want on your pizza:");        
            }
        }); //Used for activating the buttons once they're pressed.

        button2 = new JButton("Medium");
        button2.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button2.setActionCommand("Medium");
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(button2);
        button2.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                button.setVisible(true);
                button.setText("Pepperoni");
                button2.setVisible(true);
                button2.setText("Cheese");
                button3.setVisible(true);
                button3.setText("Pineapple");
//Set text is to keep the buttons but change the text within them & button 4,5, and 6 are for new buttons to be created
                button4 = new JButton("Mushrooms");
                button4.setActionCommand("Mushrooms");
//setFont is for changing the font of the buttons in the actionPerformed sub-method.
                button4.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button4);
                button5 = new JButton("Peppers");
                button5.setActionCommand("Peppers");
                button5.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button5);
                button6 = new JButton("Bacon");
                button6.setActionCommand("Bacon");
                button6.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button6);
                label.setVisible(true);
                label.setText("Please choose what topping you want on your pizza:");    

//Text below is for creating new buttons within the actionPerformed sub-method so that I'm able to add crust options.
                if (button.getText().equals("Thin Crust"));{
                    button.setText("Thin Crust");
                }
                }
            });

        button3 = new JButton("Large");
        button3.setAlignmentY(JButton.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
//Right Alignment is used for changing the button's location on the panel so they're able to be lined up.
        button3.setActionCommand("Large");
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(button3);
        button3.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                button.setVisible(true);
                button.setText("Pepperoni");
                button2.setVisible(true);
                button2.setText("Cheese");
                button3.setVisible(true);
                button3.setText("Pineapple");
                button4 = new JButton("Mushrooms");
                button4.setActionCommand("Mushrooms");
                button4.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button4);
                button5 = new JButton("Peppers");
                button5.setActionCommand("Peppers");
                button5.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button5);
                button6 = new JButton("Bacon");
                button6.setActionCommand("Bacon");
                button6.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
                contentPane.add(button6);
                label.setVisible(true);
                label.setText("Please choose what topping you want on your pizza:");                

                button.isEnabled();
            }
        });
        frame.add(contentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


//Used to run the GUI once the program ha sstarted running.
    private static void runGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
//Adds borders to the GUI window.
        PizzaMain size = new PizzaMain();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//InvokeLate is used for updating the GUI; such as changing the buttons or changing a label after a button is pressed.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runGUI();
            }
        });
    }

//Used to override since I was getting errors without it.
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I expect the output to be that once a button for a topping is pressed, it will go onto a third set of buttons for more options for the pizza instead of not doing anything at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are going to make button3 visible after you clicked on it? not sure what your question is about, but I would recommend re-reading your code

Comment: you can do is First make the next set of buttons non-visible, then just as the pizza is selected, make those buttons visible

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps JCheckBoxes and JRadioButtons with a single submit button might be better suited for your needs than using buttons for each selection. If you still need Listeners, all JComponents have ActionListeners, or a listener better suited for that component, JCheckBoxes and JRadioButton has ItemListener and ChangeListener as well.

If you wish to stick with JButtons, I'd recommend moving buttons grouped together to a JPanel and managing the visibility for that to true or false. In addition, I'd have the buttons as + and - for more or less of a topping and have an integer field to store how much of that topping the user has specified, if double toppings is an option.

Something I figured out the hard way, the best way to control GUI elements is through JPanels. Need that JLabel a certain size or position? Wrap it in a JPanel and mold that to what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class PizzaMain implements ActionListener {
 final static String LABEL_TEXT = "Please choose the size of your pizza:";
StringBuilder selectedOutput = new StringBuilder();
JFrame frame;
JPanel contentPane;
JLabel label;
JButton button, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6;
 /*Button 4,5,6 will be used for more toppings.
 JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, & JButton is used for adding the variables of all 
 the buttons, panels, labels, and frame so they're able to be added into the 
 JPanel in GUI.*/ 

public PizzaMain() {
    frame = new JFrame("EAST SIDE PIZZA");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

    label = new JLabel(LABEL_TEXT);
    label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    contentPane.add(label);
    label.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.ITALIC, 15));

    //Add other pizza buttons here  Size buttons ..Small Pizza,Large Pizza ,Medium Pizza,Family Size
    //Once these buttons are created add then to the contentPane
    //Since your user initial point of entry
    button = new JButton("Small");
    button.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    button.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button.setActionCommand("Small");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(button);
    button.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));

    JButton largePizza = new JButton("Large");
    largePizza.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    largePizza.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    largePizza.setActionCommand("Large");
    largePizza.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(largePizza);

    //This panel is displayed on the second stage after the user has selected his/her Pizza size
    //Add other pizza type button  Pepperoni,Cheese,Ham,blah blah
    //add these buttons to jpanel
    //set each button actionListener  copy paste
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    jPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    jPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    button4 = new JButton("Pepperoni");
    button4.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    button4.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button4.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
    button4.addActionListener(this);
    jPanel.add(button4);

    button5 = new JButton("Cheese");
    button5.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    button5.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button5.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
    button5.addActionListener(this);
    jPanel.add(button5);


    //This page is the last selection stage you can have many pages in form of JPanel as above
    //add other options here ,veggetables,topping
    //add them to jPanel2
    JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();
    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
    jPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    jPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    button6 = new JButton("Vegetables");
    button6.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    button6.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button6.setActionCommand("Small in Japen2");
    button6.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
    button6.addActionListener(this);

    JButton button7 = new JButton("meat");
    button7.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    button7.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    button7.setActionCommand("Small in Japen2");
    button7.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
    button7.addActionListener(this);
    jPanel2.add(button7);

    JButton backButtonToPanel1 = new JButton("<<<");
    backButtonToPanel1.setAlignmentX(JButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    backButtonToPanel1.setAlignmentY(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    backButtonToPanel1.setFont(new Font("Papyrus", Font.ITALIC, 13));
    backButtonToPanel1.addActionListener(this);
    jPanel2.add(backButtonToPanel1);

    JTextField output = new JTextField();
    jPanel2.add(output);

    /*button to select another option following option {pepperoni,cheese} these options are found in jPanel2
    When user chooses small pizza  contentPane will removeAll its childrens,repaint its self and validate its action
    It will repaint itself again and then add second panel
    User selected option is then stored in a StringBuilder log will show the activity
    Once done it will take the user to the next Panel for more options
    This step is used to define buttons actions*/
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selectedOutput.append("selected -> small");
            contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.add(jPanel);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            System.out.println("small clicked will take you to jpanel 1");
        }
    });

    largePizza.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selectedOutput.append("selected -> Large Pizza");
            contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.add(jPanel);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            System.out.println("large clicked will take you to jpanel 1");
        }
    });

    // button to select the following optins  {pepperoni,meat} options in JPanel 2
    button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selectedOutput.append("   and,pepperoni");
            output.setText(selectedOutput.toString());
            contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.add(jPanel2);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            System.out.println("large clicked will take you to jpanel 2");
        }
    });

    // button to select the following optins  {pepperoni,meat} options in JPanel 2
    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            selectedOutput.append("   and,cheese");
            output.setText(selectedOutput.toString());
            contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.add(jPanel2);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            System.out.println("This will remain here showing user final option");
        }
    });

    button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            output.setText("");
            selectedOutput.append("  topped with meat");
            output.setText(selectedOutput.toString());
            contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.add(jPanel2);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            System.out.println("This will remain here showing user final option");

        }
    });

    backButtonToPanel1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            contentPane.removeAll();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
            contentPane.add(jPanel);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            System.out.println("We are going back");

        }
    });
    frame.add(contentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void runGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    PizzaMain size = new PizzaMain();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runGUI();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

The above solution uses JPanels and dynamic page layout.
**How it works**
First page(**JPanel1**) is displayed were user can select Pizza sizes *{small,medium,Large}* After selecting Pizza size the Another Page is the displayed **(JPanel2)**.

In JPanel2 user can have other options to choose pizza type as well as an option to return to JPanel1.

Console will help you with all the activities that are happening.

***NB**  i have added a JTextField at the last JPanel to show all the selected user options.